# slip1, slip2 in URDF

Tags: gazebo, skid-steer

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working on URDF model of skid steering robot (Pioneer 3AT). There is new plugin for controlling this type of robot (see [gazebo_plugins package](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins)) so, I can command robot from ROS and it moves. But I have problems with rotational movements - robot can't rotate. If I define wheels (collision geometry) as very thin cylinders and apply high torque it "somehow" rotates... If collision geometry is defined using mesh it's better but, robot jumps a bit.

The question is - how can I set slip1/slip2 (as setting this is recommended [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1505/how-do-i-set-up-mu-and-slip-for-a-skid-steer-robot/?answer=1506#post-id-1506)) using URDF? As far as I know, URDF is translated into SDF so, I guess, it should be somehow possible. Thanks for hints in advance.

I'm using Gazebo 1.8 and gazebo_ros_pkgs for ROS integration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3334/slip1,-slip2-in-urdf/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

URDF has no concept of friction, so you'll have to insert SDF (which is currently specified using the  extension).

Something like

```
  <gazebo reference="r_foot">
    <!-- kp and kd for rubber -->
    <kp>1000000.0</kp>
    <kd>100.0</kd>
    <mu1>1.5</mu1>
    <mu2>1.5</mu2>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
    <minDepth>0.00</minDepth>
  </gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-06-27**:
This is documented [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo#.3Cgazebo.3E_Elements_For_Links)